# Can not import the csv package

Tags: java, android, csv

i downloaded the library for reading the csv files from [this website](http://flatpack.sourceforge.net/) 
and as mentioned when i tried to import the package using import command au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;
eclipse undelines it with red. 
my question is: can anyone tell me how to properly import this pacage?

to note:i imported the package into my project through building path,configur build path-libraries-adding external jars.

Comment: Did you forget to add the jar to your project in Eclipse?  :)

Answer (score 0):

The library was written based on Java SE. There are many reasons why it may not be compatible with the Android SDK.